# DispatchProxy instance TypeLoadException on method calls returning a generic type

Tags: c#, .net-core, aop

I can't seem to call a function that has this signature:

> IGenericHandler GetHandler(T input) where T : GenericBase;

Here's a dotnetfiddle reproducing the exception

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lu1iSN

Did I implemented DispatchProxy in a bad way, is it a limitation of the class or is this a bug in the DispatchProxy class?